# nginx + php-fpm - php works except cannot use $_GET

Tags: url, nginx, get, php

I'm rolling my own mvc framework starting with a front controller, which is working - all requests go through /index.php, which is loading bootstrap files eg router.php.

However, $_GET isn't working, so my router.php file isn't working. My URL scheme will simply be /controller/view with .php omitted, but as yet I can't change URLs because I can't $_GET the url to pass to router.php (to load the correct controller and view).

I have searched everywhere for solutions and found this similar post on stackoverflow, but it's recommended fix doesn't work for me:
https://serverfault.com/questions/231578/nginx-php-fpm-where-are-my-get-params

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name mvcapp; 
    #Remove Trailing Slash '/'
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    root /usr/local/var/www/mvcapp/public; 
    index index.php;        


    location / {
        # Neither of the below 2 lines work
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    #proxy Non-static requests to nginx
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Include the default fastcgi_params file included with Nginx
        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    # Pass to upstream PHP-FPM;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     }

}
```

My knowledge of php-fpm is very weak - so perhaps I am missing a fastcgi_param?

What do you see wrong?

(thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass the URI as a get parameter, do something like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
```

Your `index.php` will see as if you used `index.php?/controller/view`

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, yes that's what I wrote in my previous comment that fixed this... but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post an answer to my own question for 48hrs, so my answer got buried in a 'small print' comment. I've ticked yours as it's identical and is the right answer, which will be more obvious to others visiting this question. Many thanks for your reply.